# Animate hero elements between AngularJS routes

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a DOM element from one position to another across a route change. For example:

```
+------+
|    o |   (o = the element)
|      |
|      |
+------+
```

Click the button, route changes. On the new template, the button is down here:

```
+------+
|      |
|      |
|    o |
+------+
```

Right now I have two separate html files for the views and the buttons are two separate DOM elements. How can I animate the button from one position to the other during the route change?

Edit: I built an example of what I want to accomplish [here](http://emzy.cc/1-material-animations/index.html). The key component missing from the example is that the two pages are on the same route. I want to animate this transition cross-route, with entire different content on each page except one common, animated, hero element.

I also discovered that the term for what I am trying to do is "hero element" and updated the question title.

Comment: you could do this with css. Just assign some class to the element when the route changes and use css transitions

Comment: It isn't quite so simple though, since the element is destroyed on the old route and constructed in the new one.

Comment: Still easy to do with css transitions. Just do it when the new route loads

Comment: @ribsies I added some more detail and an example to the question to give a better idea of what I'm trying to create.

Comment: So you are trying to not only animate an element but somehow morph one element into a completely different one. This is not possible. Animating is easy, youre going to have to rethink what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this tutorial (ready made component to use as well), it animates hero elements between different views and maintains proper routes.

http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/12/19/angular-hero-transitions.html

To summarize, the hero element has to exist between the two views being transitioned. When transitioning, the hero element is temporarily hidden in the target view till the position animation ends. 
If the target view is being loaded directly (refresh, bookmark), no animation takes place and the hero element is there.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you are using angularjs,

You can either create sub route in that html only and swap out that little sub route for templates.

or u can do ng-include with ng-switch for the button to do that instead of the whole html.

EDIT: i made a jsbin for you. hope this helps.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cepili/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your solution. Would you mind creating a simple example?

Comment: Sorry I'm away from my computer now.. Maybe I'll provide a fiddle later. For now u can try looking at ng-switch examples and also ng-include.. U can either put ur little box in a html file and include it in the dom based on the click or put it in a div so that u can show n hide them based on the clicks, either using no-show and ng-hide or ng-switch

Comment: @emzy are you trying to do something like u click the button, and the button slides from top to bottom while the content changes?

Comment: Exactly. I added some details to the question, plus an example.

Comment: @emzy try the jsbin i made for you.. hope it helps.

Comment: The real trick is being able to animate across routes, that's what the question is. We can't realistically build our entire complex, bookmarkable apps on a single route, can we?